# Julia bulk insert into SQL Server

Tags: sql, r, julia

Using R, I can bulk insert data into SQL Server using dbWriteTable and passing it the name of the table and the name of the dataframe. dbWriteTable will even create the table for me in SQL Server if it does not already exist. Is there a package in Julia that offers the same functionality (I'm using v.1.0.1? If not, is it a matter of looping through the data and inserting row by row?

Comment: I am not sure there is a method to do this with SQL Server, although there is one in SQLite (https://discourse.julialang.org/t/write-dataframe-to-sqlite-table/8319). 
It seems you can do the iterative data entry into SQL Server with either with JDBC.jl or ODBC.jl (https://juliadatabases.org/).

Comment: While I understand that "bulk insert" does not always mean this, to me it typically involves the use of a command-line (not R) utility that transfers and inserts the data as efficiently as the database authors can supports, which can be *significantly* faster than `DBI::dbWriteTable` depending on the data size. For SQL Server, this would be `bcp` (or `sqlcmd`); for PostgreSQL, it's `psql`. While not an awesome solution, it would certainly be faster in julia to write to a CSV and bulk-insert via the external tool.